# How can i run a sudo command in Bash script?

Tags: bash, shell

I want to run the following sample bash script which needs sudo password for a command

```
#!/bin/bash
kinit #needs sudo password
vi hello.txt
```

while running the above script it is asking for password.
How can i pass the username and password in the command itself or is there any better way i can skip passing my password in the script ?

Answer (score 9):

### TL;DR

You can't—at least, not the way you think.

### Longer Answer with Alternatives

You have a couple of options:

1. Authenticate interactively with *sudo* before running your script, e.g. `sudo -v`. The credentials will be temporarily cached, giving you time to run your script.
2. Add a specific command such as */usr/lib/klibc/bin/kinit* to your sudoers file with the NOPASSWD option. See sudoers(5) and and visudo(8) for syntax.
3. Use gksudo(1) or kdesu(1) with the appropriate keyring to cache your credentials if you're using a desktop environment.

One or more of these will definitely get you where you want to go—just not the way you wanted to get there.

Answer (score 8):

So if you have access to your full system, you can change your sudoers file to allow certain sudo commands to be run w/o a password.

1. On the command line run `visudo`
2. Find your user and change the line to look something like this:

```bash
pi ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /path/to/kinit, /path/to/another/command
```

That should do it. Give it another shot!

Hope that helps

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't pass username and password. This is not secure and it is not going to work if the password is changed.

You can use this:

```
gksudo kinit # This is going to open a dialog asking for the password.
#sudo kinit # or this if you want to type your password in the terminal
vi hello.txt
```

Or you can run your script under root. But note that vi is going to be ran as root as well, which means that it will probably create files that belong to root, that might be not what you want.