# Error: Tar command not found

Tags: bash, shell, unix, tar

```
    echo "Enter path of backup file e.g /tmp/backup/etc.tar.gz : "
    read PATH    #input was /tmp/backup/etc.tar.gz
    echo "Enter directory: " 
    read DIR    #input was /root/testing

    sudo tar -zvxf "$PATH" -C "$DIR"
```

when I ran the script, it said that the command was not found. I tried using whatever kind of brackets for the variables but still not working. Any help?

However when I ran the command tar -zvxf /tmp/backup/etc.tar.gz -C /root/testing , it worked.

Comment: and/or the sudo-in-a-script problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18364714/how-can-i-run-a-sudo-command-in-bash-script

Comment: Yes tar is installed when i tried the command seperately it worked. It was the same without the sudo.

Comment: type `which tar` to find out the full path of tar and use the full path in the script (e.g. `sudo /usr/bin/tar ...`) if which returned `/usr/bin/tar`

Comment: The `sudo` issue revolves around `sudo` requiring the user to enter their password manually, when the script runs.  As long as that's acceptable, there is no problem with `sudo` in a script.

Comment: tried using /usr/bin/tar not working too.

Comment: Since PATH is a special environment variable, it may not be the best choice. Can you try some other name?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. [Super User](http://superuser.com/tour) is a question and answer site for computer enthusiasts and power users.

Comment: OMG thanks! I changed the PATH to some other variable name. Thanks alot! Didn't realised that mistake.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're saving something into `PATH` which is what the shell will search to find the executables.  So when you use that variable the shell can't find, say, `tar` because it is no longer in your search path.  Use a different variable name.

Comment: This is why lowercase names are recommended for shell variables -- all of the "special" environment variables are uppercase, so if you stick to lowercase you'll never accidentally step on one and break something. See [this previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/673055/correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization).